# How to set priority for test methods execution using TestNG + JAVA Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have trying to execute my test script with the help of reflections which has annotated as @Test as following way:

```
Class<?> className = Class.forName(format);  //Load the class name at runtime

                Constructor<?> customConstructor = className.getConstructor(WebDriver.class);   //Create customized constructor and initalize driver from testbase


Method[] method = className.getMethods();  //Call the list of methods in current class file

                for (Method me : method) {
                    if (me.getName().startsWith("test")) {   //Check wheather the class prefix as test

                        Method getMethods = Class.forName(format).getDeclaredMethod(me.getName());   //Loading all the methods at runtime.
                        if(getMethods.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class))
                        {
//The method which is annotated @Test will execute here, using invoke() method of reflection.
}
}
```

But, the problem is not able to run the @Test methods as per priority value. Its executing randomly. Can anybody tell me how could I run the @test methods based on priority value.

Also, I tried the same with dependsOnMethods. But still Its randomly executing.

Sample code:

```
package com.test.build;

import com.test.build.ClassA;
import com.test.build.ClassB;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParentClass {

    @Test
    public void executeTestMetods() throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type package name");
        String name = scan.next();
        Class<?> class1 = Class.forName(name);
        Method[] method = class1.getMethods();

        for (Method me : method) {
            if (me.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class)) {
                if (me.getName().startsWith("test")) {
                    System.out.println(me.getName());
                }
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

ClassA

```
package com.test.build;

import org.testng.annotations.Test; 

@Test(singleThreaded  = true)
public class ClassA {

    @Test(priority=0)
    public void test1()
    {
        System.out.println("class A");
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A second method");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)

    public void test3()
    {
        System.out.println("class A");
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void test4()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A second method");
    }

    @Test(priority=4)

    public void test5()
    {
        System.out.println("class A");
    }

    @Test(priority=5)
    public void test6()
    {
        System.out.println("Class A second method");
    }

}
```

Output:

Type package name
com.test.build.ClassA
test3
test4
test5
test6
test1
test2
PASSED: executeTestMetods

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

The output is not properly executed as per priority, and shows randomly invoked. How to make it sequence execution?

Comment: You shouldn't. The only reason why you might have a priority in your tests is to enforce an order in the execution, and the only reason for that is because you have tests that depend on other tests. This is a big NO-NO in TDD: all your tests should be independent and setup/clear all the state required. I highly recommend you re-design them if this is the case, or think about why you need priority at all if that's not the case.

Comment: (Also, you should really indent properly the code you post)

Answer (score 0):

TestNG provides inbox a dedicated feature to do what you want: [Annotation transformers](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers).