# How to execute TestNG test methods in sequence order using JAVA reflection

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I have a @Test method(ParentClass) and named as mainTest, and had situation to call n number of @Test methods which is in another class(ClassA(test1,test2), ClassB(test3,test4)) files, and declared inside of the mainTest. When I execute the mainTest method It has to execute the @Test methods which is called inside of mainTest in sequence order using reflection. Can somebody give me any inputs?

Comment: Why not using testng API instead of using reflection? BTW, you should provide a concrete example if you want an appropriate answer.

Comment: Please find the code sample in below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695496/how-to-set-priority-for-test-methods-execution-using-testng-java-reflection